I need an MMA function to convert two lists like {0, r} {s, 0} in one list of rules {0->"s","r"->0}
I need a Math.  function  to convert two lists like {0, r}
{s, 0} in one list {0->"s","r"->0}; I.e. the letters must be enclosed in " ", but the numbers not. I have one solution:
l2L = Function[{list1, list2}, 
   MapThread[
    Rule[If[NumericQ[#1], #1, "\"" <> ToString[#1] <> "\""], 
      If[NumericQ[#2], #2, "\"" <> ToString[#2] <> "\""]] &, {list1, 
     list2}]];

which  works
l2L[{0, r, r, i, i, s, s, s}, {s, 0, s, 0, r, 0, r, i}]

but it beeps on 13.3, saying "Assuming a list of rules. Use as a list instead"  Can you provide a better version?
For a more challenging example, I need to convert
l1={0, 2 r, 2 r, i + r, i + r, r + s, r + s, r + s}; l2={s, r, r + s, r, 2 r, r, 2 r, i + r};

Here a variation of the answer of @Ajerbajzdan
l2L = Replace[Thread[#1 -> #2], x_Symbol :> ToString[x], {2, 3}] &;
l2L[l1, l2]
works, but beeps. And if I put just {2} or  {3} some letters are not enclosed in " "

Replace[Thread[{0, r, r, i, i, s, s, s} -> {s, 0, s, 0, r, 0, r, i}], 
 x_Symbol :> ToString[x], All]


{0 -> "s", "r" -> 0, "r" -> "s", "i" -> 0, "i" -> "r", "s" -> 0, "s" -> "r", "s" -> "i"}

Works also with new example:
l1 = {0, 2 r, 2 r, i + r, i + r, r + s, r + s, r + s};
l2 = {s, r, r + s, r, 2 r, r, 2 r, i + r};
Replace[Thread[l1 -> l2], x_Symbol :> ToString[x], All]


{0 -> "s", 2 "r" -> "r", 2 "r" -> "r" + "s", "i" + "r" -> "r", 
 "i" + "r" -> 2 "r", "r" + "s" -> "r", "r" + "s" -> 2 "r", 
 "r" + "s" -> "i" + "r"}


I added a more complicated example, where I am not sure how to adjust the level (and it beeps)

@Florin I edited my answer. You can use All instead of {2} for level specification.

A beauty of conciseness and efficiency

A level spec of {-1} is probably more efficient.

This is the second question I remember about this sort of transformation of the OP's variables to strings. If it's a common task that arises in different sorts of expressions, it seems a general utility would be useful, instead of ad hoc questions and solutions for each case that arises. If so, here's a suggestion:
(* convert my symbols to their string names *)
mySymbolName // ClearAll;
mySymbolName // Attributes = {Listable};
$mySymbolContexts = {"Global`"}; (* defines which symbols are mine *)
mySymbolName[s_Symbol /; MemberQ[$mySymbolContexts, Context[s]]] := 
  SymbolName[s];
mySymbolName[e_] := mySymbolName /@ e; (* ignores heads *)

One could use a different test than MemberQ[$mySymbolContexts, Context[s]] to restrict which symbols are converted. It's up to the user to determine how they want the conversion restricted.
Rule @@@ mySymbolName@{{0, r}, {s, 0}}
(*  0 -> "r", "s" -> 0  *)

mySymbolName@Thread[l1 -> l2] === l2L[l1, l2]
(*  True  *)


Thanks  for your help. I apologize for not progressing more in my Mathematica skills, and lowering maybe  a bit the level of this site (I do know about Sparse and Normal though). I'm  just a user, not a Mathematica scholar.  Back to my problems (solved  for now below, I believe), they are about trying to use  output from Matlab (no strings, I guess), Mathematica and macaulay2 packages,  which deal all with chemical reaction networks, and use strings in a bewildering number of ways. These are conventions of various contributed packages I don't have control on.

@florin  Sorry if the intro felt like criticism. I can see how it might. However, I was trying to explain my motivation to post a complicated answer in a somewhat different paradigm that had the flexibility to be extended to different requirements. azerbajdzan's first code worked on your first example, but it needed adjustment for a follow-up example. SE was introduced to me as a resource for others, not just a site focused narrowly on the needs of a specific task. Often I try to complement existing answers. So for a site visitor, if the accepted answer doesn't work, one of the others might.

Using ReplaceAll:
f = # /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global`" :> ToString[s] &;

f@Thread[l1 -> l2] === Replace[Thread[l1 -> l2], x_Symbol :> ToString[x], All]


True

Edit: As @MichaelE2 pointed out, it's important to note that the replacement rule SparseArray[{0, 0, r, s, 0}] /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global" :> ToString[s] won't work directly on SparseArray objects due to how they optimize storage. If you're working with sparse arrays, you might need to convert them to a normal list first or apply the rule at the definition stage. However, using HoldForm and ReleaseHold can help avoid immediate evaluation of SparseArray and allow the replacement to happen first:
ReleaseHold[
HoldForm[SparseArray][{0, 0, r, s, 0}] /. 
s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global`" :> ToString[s]]

Thanks, Michael!

(+1) That's the first thing I thought of. I guess I wanted something that worked on sparse arrays: SparseArray[{0, 0, r, s, 0}] /.   s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global" :> ToString[s]` doesn't work. Not an issue on the OP's problem, though. Just thought I'd point out the difference.

Hi @MichaelE2! First off, thanks for pointing out that important detail about SparseArray—it's definitely something to keep in mind. Working with sparse arrays does add a layer of complexity when it comes to pattern matching and replacement rules, as you pointed out.
